# Improve map plot

Tags: r, dictionary, polygon, spatial

I am still quite new to R and trying to make my map more beautiful. Despite all the information on the internet, nothing seems to work for my problem.
When i plot the map i can still see the white lines and i want to increase either the point size or delete the white lines in any way. I tried cex and other graphic parameters but besides the size of the legend or the title nothing changes. Since i am just getting started with spatial plotting, further suggestions for improvement are gladly accepted! Thank you

[image: see first map result]

[image: Head of the data]

```
 par(mfrow=c(1,1), cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.3, cex.main=1.5, mar=c(0,1.5,1.2,1.5))

 int <- classIntervals(Large spatial polygon dataframe@data$X, n=15,   style="quantile",precision=2)
 colours              <- findColours(int, palette, cutlabels=FALSE)

 plot("Large spatial polygon dataframe", col=colours, border=rgb(0,0,0,0.05), las=1, lwd=0.25 ,lty=2,main="X", adj=0)

 legend("bottomleft", legend=paste0("<",round(int$brks[-1],digits=0)),    fill=palette, border=palette,
 bty="n", title="", cex=1.3, y.intersp = 0.75)
 data(wrld_simpl)
 wrld_simpl.sp <- spTransform(wrld_simpl, "+proj=moll")
 plot(wrld_simpl.sp,add=T)
```

Comment: I highly recommend the use of the packages ```ggplot2``` and ```ggspatial``` for the creation of spatial plots

Comment: can you share some data we can use?

Comment: I tried to share some data with dput but failed miserably- gonna try again to save and share some data but for now i provided the data head (hope this still helps a little bit). Sorry i am used to working with normal dataframes and still be overwhelmed with this polygon dataframe thing..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started with `ggplot2`.  It will provide you with alot of flexibility when you get used to it.

```
library(maptools)
library(sf)
library(data.table)

#retrieve dataset
data(wrld_simpl)
dt <- wrld_simpl

#set sp to sf (I prefer sf over sp)
dt <- st_as_sf(dt)

#transform to desired projection (just an example)
dt <- dt %>% st_transform(4326)

#add some data and create intervals

  #set as data.table
setDT(dt)

  #add data
dt[, data := 1:nrow(dt)]

  #determine quantiles
quant <- round(quantile(dt$data, c(0.2,0.4)))

  #create category column and group data in a quantile category
dt[data < quant[1], category := paste0("<", quant[1])]
dt[data >= quant[1] & data < quant[2], category := paste0(quant[1], "-", quant[2])]
dt[data >= quant[2], category := paste0(">", quant[2])]

  #set to sf
dt <- st_as_sf(dt)

#create plot
ggplot(dt) + geom_sf(aes(fill = category), col = "black", size = 0.001) + 
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") + 
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) + theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
```

[image: figure]